# Why doesn't the button label show what is in string.xml? (Android UI basics)

Tags: xml, android-layout, user-interface, android

This is what the UI looks like in the SDK

[image]
This is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphBoarder
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graphAxes"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/graphAxes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:onClick="btnFreq1"
        android:text="@string/btn1Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="btnFreq2"
        android:text="@string/btn2Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:onClick="btnFreq3"
        android:text="@string/btn3Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="btnFreq4"
        android:text="@string/btn4Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="btnFreq5"
        android:text="@string/btn5Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="btnFreq6"
        android:text="@string/btn6Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="btnFreq7"
        android:text="@string/btn7Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="btnFreq8"
        android:text="@string/btn8Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:onClick="btnPrevClk"
        android:text="@string/btnPrevText"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="btnSetGraphClk"
        android:text="@string/btnSetGraph"
        android:textSize="12sp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:text="@string/txtView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/txtView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/txtView2" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

But the output on screen looks slightly different than this

[image]

Why does it show 0 where it should show 1K and 3K? I thought it had something to do with my fixing the width to some hardcoded value, but even with layout_width = "match_parent" it is still showing the same problem.

--- EDIT ---
This is the strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My Basic Interactive Graph</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="btn1Text">125 Hz</string>
    <string name="btn2Text">250 Hz</string>
    <string name="btn3Text">500 Hz</string>
    <string name="btn4Text">1k</string>
    <string name="btn5Text">2k</string>
    <string name="btn6Text">3k</string>
    <string name="btn7Text">4k</string>
    <string name="btn8Text">6k</string>
    <string name="txtView1">Gain</string>
    <string name="txtView2">Q factor</string>
    <string name="txtView3">Centre freq</string>
    <string name="btnPrevText">Prev</string>
    <string name="btnSetGraph">Confirm</string>

</resources>
```

--- EDIT 2 ---
Updated (working) xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphBoarder
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graphAxes"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/graphAxes"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:onClick="btnFreq1"
        android:text="@string/btn1Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:onClick="btnFreq2"
        android:text="@string/btn2Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:onClick="btnFreq3"
        android:text="@string/btn3Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
        android:onClick="btnFreq4"
        android:text="@string/btn4Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="btnFreq5"
        android:text="@string/btn5Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:onClick="btnFreq6"
        android:text="@string/btn6Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
        android:onClick="btnFreq7"
        android:text="@string/btn7Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
        android:onClick="btnFreq8"
        android:text="@string/btn8Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button8"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:onClick="btnPrevClk"
        android:text="@string/btnPrevText"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="btnSetGraphClk"
        android:text="@string/btnSetGraph"
        android:textSize="12sp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button4"
        android:text="@string/txtView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button10"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/txtView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button10"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/txtView2" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant past of strings.xml?

Comment: strings.xml added to the question

Comment: Do you have strings.xml in other values-XX folders?

Comment: no this is the only one

Comment: If you do not have strings.xml in other values-XXX folders, the only other chance is that you are setting the text programatically.

Comment: the button text is not set programatically. Why does the longer text 125 Hz wrap to two lines, where the shorter text 1k shows up as 0? It looks proper in the SDK screenshots, so why not in the final output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're not using `@+id` and `@id` correctly. `@+id` should be used only once.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphBoarder
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp" />

<com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/graphAxes"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view"
    android:layout_below="@id/view"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/graphAxes"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:onClick="btnFreq1"
    android:text="@string/btn1Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:onClick="btnFreq2"
    android:text="@string/btn2Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:onClick="btnFreq3"
    android:text="@string/btn3Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
    android:onClick="btnFreq4"
    android:text="@string/btn4Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/button5"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:onClick="btnFreq5"
    android:text="@string/btn5Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:onClick="btnFreq6"
    android:text="@string/btn6Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/button7"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
    android:onClick="btnFreq7"
    android:text="@string/btn7Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
    android:onClick="btnFreq8"
    android:text="@string/btn8Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button8"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
    android:onClick="btnPrevClk"
    android:text="@string/btnPrevText"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnSetGraphClk"
    android:text="@string/btnSetGraph"
    android:textSize="12sp" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button4"
    android:text="@string/txtView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button10"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:text="@string/txtView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button10"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/txtView2" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to solve the problem. But again, why doesn't it show up on the SDK? And is the order in which the buttons are declared in the xml file important in any way? For example, please check the updated xml file I will post to my question. Take for example, `button 2` -> `android:id="@+id/button2"`. In this code block, in the line `android:layout_above="@+id/button5"` the compiler shows an error and says button5 not declared. Why is that?

Comment: The order is important for z-order for instance. What is important though, is to always declare each variable once with `@+id`.

Comment: so let's take the declaration of button2 for instance. If I don't put `+` in the line `android:layout_above="@+id/button5"` it does not compile. So does this mean when I really do declare button5, I do not need to give `+`, in the line `android:id="@+id/button5"`? How exactly does declaring variable in xml work? And what is z-order?

Comment: Basically, you have to declare the variable the first time (line) you use it.

Comment: Z-order means which view is on top of which if they are in the same location, eg using relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

Check "@string/btn6Text" and "@string/btn4Text" - are they holding the right values ? You have to look at the values xmls.

If they are holding the correct values, You can try to rebuild the project after you are done Clean / refreshing the workspace.

UPDATE

Caught the issue - Check for the @+id and @id - in your xml.

> When you have @+id -> the android creates a variable for you.
>
> simply @id -> will try to reference an existing value, since there is
>   no variable it sets the default values which is apparently 0.

Comment: that's not the problem here. Why does the longer text `125 Hz` wrap to two lines, where the shorter text 1k shows up as 0? And we can see from the SDK screenshots that the value in strings.xml is correct.

Comment: Caught the issue - Check for the @+id and @id - in your xml.

Comment: @takrishna That's exactly what I pointed out 4 minutes before your edit. Try to not repeat what the others said, please.

Comment: Thanks that seems to solve the problem. But again, why doesn't it show up on the SDK? And is the order in which the buttons are declared in the xml file important in any way? For example, please check the updated xml file I will post to my question. Take for example, `button 2` -> `android:id="@+id/button2"`. In this code block, in the line `android:layout_above="@+id/button5"` the compiler shows an error and says button5 not declared. Why is that?

Comment: @Szymon hey no offence here. :) I just replied over email didn't see your reply. @ poster of this question please mark his answer correct. :P

Comment: @takrishna No worries.